# How to run ruby program on the Raspbian OS?

Tags: ruby, raspbian

How do I run a ruby program on my Raspberry Pi 3? My Pi is running Raspbian.

My Ruby program was written on my laptop using RubyMine.

Comment: Ruby is designed to be relatively platform-independent. Have you tried installing Ruby on your Pi and running the command `ruby path/to/file.rb`?

Comment: Why not just install it and run?